# Drop down Menu going to right instead of straight down

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu

Hey guys I am having an issue with a drop down menu. Instead of my submenu going straight down they are lining up like they are inline. It is becoming quite frustrating. Any help appreciated. Here is my code for the CSS and HTML.

```
* DROP DOWN MENU-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#navmenu{
margin-top:3%;
margin-bottom:6%;
}
ul#menu li{
position:static;
float:left;
text-align:center;
list-style-type:none;
}
#menu a{
text-decoration:none;
}





#menu a{
    text-decoration:none;
    border:2px solid black;
    width:240px;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:25px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 3px #99ccff;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px #99ccff;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #99ccff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 3px 3px #99ccff;
    /*background-color:#3399ff;
    color:white;*/
    margin-right:6%;
}
.sub{
display:none;
position:absolute;
z-index:9;
text-align:left;

}
ul#menu li:hover .sub{
display:block;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="navmenu">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Internet</a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Agreement</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">MTTV</a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li> derp</li>
                <li>derp</li>
                <li>derp</li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Telephone</a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li>derp </li>
                <li>derp</li>
                <li>derp </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Pay Your Bill</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Check Your E-mail</a>   </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Classifieds</a></li>
        </ul>



    </div>
    <br id="break">
    <div class="slider-wrap">
        <div id="main-photo-slider" class="csw">
            <div class="panelContainer">

                <div class="panel" title="Panel 1"id="panel 1">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <a href="#"><img src="espn.jpg" alt="temp" /></a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel" title="Panel 2" id="panel 2">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <a href="#"><img src="facebook.jpg" alt="temp" /></a>

                    </div>
                </div>      
                <div class="panel" title="Panel 3" id="panel 3">
                    <div class="wrapper">

                        <a href="#"><img src="appalachian.jpg" alt="app" /></a>


                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>





            </div>
            <a  class ="cross-link active-thumb" href="#1"><button aria-label="Go to img #1" id ="img 1" class="nav-thumb"></button></a>
                <a  class ="cross-link" href="#2"><button aria-label="Go to img #2" id="img 2" class="nav-thumb"></button></a>
                    <a  class ="cross-link" href="#3"><button aria-label="Go to img #3" id="img 2" class="nav-thumb "></button></a>

        </div>
```

I do have a slideshow for in the middle of the page that is handled by JS. However I do have a Z-index on my items. All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please add these styles to your CSS:

```
ul.sub {
    width: 245px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

[jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/h3Lwz7z9/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li></br>
            <li><a href="#">Agreement</a></li></br>
            <li><a href="#">Something</a></li></br>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS works fine for me: you can use your suggested HTML list (though you can remove the `class="sub"`). Also, you can have upto 3 levels of submenus (just embed another `<ul>` inside a `<li>`; you can also edit the code to have even more subs). Just edit the comments as needed.

```
#navmenu {
  margin-top:3%;
  margin-bottom:6%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99;/*Set this as high as needed to let the menu unfold on top of the rest of your site (instead of below other elements)*/
} 

#navmenu ul {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#navmenu li {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 240px;/*Set here your menu with*/
}

#navmenu ul a,
#navmenu ul a:visited {
  display: block;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  border:2px solid black;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 3px #99ccff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 4px #99ccff;
  border-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #99ccff;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0px 3px 3px #99ccff;
}

#navmenu > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* width: auto; *//* Set this to auto if you want the main menu items to have a just the width they need */
  height: 25px;
}

#navmenu > ul > li > a,
#navmenu > ul > li > a:visited {
  padding: 0 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navmenu li:hover {
  /*Hover style*/
}

#navmenu li:hover > a,
#navmenu li:hover > a:visited {
  color: #ee9;
}

#navmenu > ul > li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    line-height:25px;
    text-align:left;
    z-index: 99;
}

#navmenu > ul > li > ul {
    min-width:100%;
}

#navmenu > ul > li > ul li {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}

#navmenu > ul > li > ul > li a,
#navmenu > ul > li > ul > li a:visited {
    line-height:25px;
    padding:0 8px;
}

#navmenu > ul > li > ul > li ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    top:0;
}

#navmenu > ul > li:hover > ul,
#navmenu > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul,
#navmenu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```